# PyQt6 Create a bar with minimum features on minimizing the window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, minimize, pyqt6

I want to create a bar with minimum control features when minimizing the main application window, similar to the bar in the image below but in PyQt6.

[image]

Currently, I am creating a new small screen on the minimize action but I could not remove the bar which has the close, minimize and maximize buttons from it.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also, "minimize" usually means that the window is hidden and only shown in the task manager, which is clearly not what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I found it is actually called a floating dialog bar
I was able to finally do it, I will add the answer to the question

Thanks a lot @musicamante

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got it and I was able to write the below code to produce it

```
class FloatingDialogBar(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, project: str = None, task: str = None):
        super(FloatingDialogBar, self).__init__(parent)

        self.project = project if project else 'N/A'
        self.task = task if task else 'N/A'

        self.__init_ui()
        self.__init_layouts()

    def greetings(self):
        # Do Something
        pass

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self.offset = event.pos()
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.offset is not None and event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self.move(self.pos() + event.pos() - self.offset)
        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.offset = None
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def __init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(
            self.windowFlags() |
            Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint |
            Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        )
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        left = 100
        top = 100
        self.width = 320
        height = 60
        self.setGeometry(
            left,
            top,
            self.width,
            height,
        )
        self.setMaximumWidth(self.width)
        self.setMinimumWidth(self.width)
        self.setMinimumHeight(height)
        self.setMaximumHeight(height)
        pass

    def __init_layouts(self):
        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet(consts.FLOATING_BAR_STYLESHEET)
        # Create widgets
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.lbl_project = QLabel(self.project)
        self.lbl_project.setStyleSheet(consts.FLOATING_BAR_QLabel_STYLESHEET)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl_project)

        self.lbl_task = QLabel(self.task)
        self.lbl_task.setStyleSheet(consts.FLOATING_BAR_QLabel_STYLESHEET)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl_task)


        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.frame.setLayout(layout)

        self.frame.setMaximumWidth(self.width)
        self.frame.setMinimumWidth(self.width)

        self.frame.setMinimumHeight(60)
        self.frame.setMaximumHeight(60)

        pass
```

Comment: Please trim down the code to the essential parts. All you need is the `setWindowFlags()` section, anything else is just pointless and irrelevant to the post. Besides, I don't know where you found that "floating dialog bar" (which seems like some bogus name someone decided on their own), that's just a *frameless window*, and certainly not a "dialog", since there is no priority communication (aka, *dialog*) between the program and the user for its main purpose as an *actual* dialog does, like in a message box. A possible name for this kind of UI could be "notification".

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @musicamante, I got the name from one of the websites while searching.